# How to Extract Data from U.S. National Landcover Dataset (NLCD) dataset?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, wgs84, erdas-imagine

I am working with U.S. National Landcover Dataset (NLCD) to classify habitat type at more than 150 sites across the northeast U.S. The dataset is very large (15GB) so I cannot upload it here, but it comes in .img format at 30m resolution. I have GPS coordinates in decimal degrees  (WGS1984) for the center point of all the sites. I would like to be able to extract the proportion of landcover classes in a 1 square kilometer around the point. My questions are:

1. How do I upload .img files into ArcGIS?
2. How do I extract the information from around the GPS coordinates as proportions of the different habitat classes?
3. How do I project my sites onto the NLCD map?
4. Should I change the projection of my coordinates?

Comment: I am also interested in doing this in r but I cant even get my sites to project on the same map either. Any advice would help.

Comment: Does the .img have a projection assigned? Does it have coordinates? Do you have ERDAS Imagine or ENVI at hand?

ArcGIS should be able to read .img files directly, as far as i can remember. Have you tried, and with what results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try something like the following as a loose workflow:

- a) buffer around the points (arcmap has a flat option to get 1km^2).
- b) merge those into a single feature class to overlay on the whole map.
- c) use the results from a) to clip tiles from the NLDS to find the data present.
- d) compile the results from c).
- e) compare results from d) to the whole map.

This assumes that you would be okay with a bit programming.